# Assign a style to a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to assign at a div named `bannerdiv` the `max-width` and the `max-weight`that coincide with the browser resolution.

I have already captured the following data:

```
$(window).width()
$(window).height()
```

How can i assign these values at the style of `bannerdiv`?

Comment: Show us the html code where bannerdiv is used.

Comment: Is `bannerdiv` an ID?

Comment: @JBDouble05 yes is an ID 
@Jeroen Heier  the html code is `<div id='bannerdiv'></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set style using jQuery use `.css()` like the following way:

```js
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
$("#bannerdiv").css('height', height);
$("#bannerdiv").css('width', width);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bannerdiv">Test</div>
```

**OR:** In a single line

```
$("#bannerdiv").css('height', height).css('width', width);
```

**OR:** Even better with property initialiser

```
$("#bannerdiv").css({ 'width' : width, 'height' : height });
```

Comment: Why not as an object instead? .css({
   'width' : width,
   'height' : height
});

Comment: @Mamum so the final solution will be : `$("#bannerdiv").css({ 'max-width' : $(window).width(), 'max-height' : $(window).height() })` , right?

Comment: @Mamun do you think that with this method Google or other advertising agencies can easly recognize the `max-width` and the `max-height` of the parent DIV?

Comment: @Daniele, yes, the could, if those properties are set to the parent DIV......thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'vw' which is viewport width and 'vh' which is viewport height, each number is representative of 1% of the viewport width(vw) or viewport height(vh) so '50vh' is 50% height of the browser window or '18vw' is 18% of the browser width.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

And Mamun is correct you can apply this directly using jQuery's .css(), but using vw and vh you don't need to capture the window height and width.

So, if bannerdiv is a class

```
$('.bannerdiv').css({'max-height': '100vh', 'max-width': '100vw'});
```

if it is an ID

```
$('#bannerdiv').css({'max-height': '100vh', 'max-width': '100vw'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bannerdiv">YourDiv</div>

$('#YourDivID').css({
'max-width' : 'YourWidthForDiv',
 'max-height' : 'YourHeightForDiv' 
});
```

You can refer [css() method Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) For More information

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You can use below snippet and in your code.

Store height and width in 2 variables:

```
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
```

Then assign value into container

```
$("#bannerdiv").attr('style','height:'+height+'px;width:'+width+'px');
```

> "attr" event will append "style" attribute in the element.